# Regex - pattern for matching Alphabet characters between brackets

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone assist in providing a Regex pattern to find letters between brackets? I.E:

[A]
or
[AAA]
or
[BAB]

The string I'm searching for could be something like this:

([A] * [B] + [AAA])

From that I'd like to be able to get the A, B, AAA out of the string. The letters I'm searching for will always be between square brackets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(?<=\[)[A-Za-z]+(?=\])
```

the matches are in bold:

> [**A**] or [**AAA**] or [**BAB**] 
>   ([**A**] * [**B**] + > [**AAA**])

You could use it like:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\[)[A-Za-z]+(?=\])");
```

Comment: A short question, what does **?<=** or **?=** do? I assume it works **only** (?) in C# regexp.

Comment: @MPękalski, `?<=` is a positive lookbehind assertion, `?=` is a positive lookahead assertion. The question is under the `c#` tag, so this should work.

Comment: @MPękalski - The syntax here is C#, but other languages (e.g. Perl) have lookahead/lookbehind.

Comment: @MPękalski: Nearly all "current" regex flavors support lookaround; JavaScript (and Ruby pre-1.9) being the notable exception in that they only support lookahead, not lookbehind. Some few regex engines also support indefinite repetition inside lookbehind assertions (.NET does, PHP/Perl/Python/Java don't support expressions like `(?<=\w*)`).

Answer (score 4):

How about this regex?

```
\[([a-zA-Z]+)\]
```

Comment: Why did you wrap the pattern with `(...)*`? I don't see any advantage there... It will combine `[a][b]` to a single match, and will add a lot of empty matches. That aside, I also prefer using a capturing group to a lookaround, when possible.